# Design Patterns for Performing Multiple Server Operations as a Single Transaction

Tags: design-patterns, stripe-payments, saas

Suppose you have a SaaS app and want to do the following when a user signs up:

1. Validate their name, email etc.
2. Create a *Stripe* Customer account for the user.
3. Subscribe the new Stripe Customer to an existing Stripe Plan.
4. Create a User record in your database which includes the Stripe info.
5. Create a new session for the user.
6. Redirect the user to your app's dashboard.

Ideally you want all these to happen in a single transaction, i.e if step 4 fails, you want to undo step 2 & 3...you don't want a dangling Stripe customer & subscription with no DB record.

What design patterns would you recommend to make such multi-step/multi-service process transactional?

#### For Context

I'm implementing this multi-step process using ES6 Promises in Node - pseudocode below:

```
async function signup_user_for_trial(req, res) {

  const {email, name, plan, password} = req.body

  if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
    throw new Error(...)
  }

  let customer = await createStripeCustomer(email)
  let subscription = await createSubscription(customer, plan)
  let user = await createDBUser(customer, name, email, password)
  let session = await createSession(req, user)

  return res.redirect('/dashboard')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I would do is build a single table responsible for referencing all of the key pieces of a transaction.  In your example, Step #2 creating a customer via the [Create a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) API Endpoint will yield a Customer ID and Step #3 attaching a plan via the [Create a Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) API Endpoint will yield a Subscription ID.

I would have two tables in your database: one that represents your users relative to their Stripe Customer ID and another that represents whether or not a user needs to be "rolled back".

In general, you'd always populate the user table.  If your process breaks somewhere though, add an entry to the "roll back" table with a User ID (or something similar) and/or an entry that indicates if you should roll back any charges too.  Have a cron-job that goes through these entries regularly to asynchronously do a few key requests:

- [Retrieve Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_customer)
- [List Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_subscriptions)
- [Cancel Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription)
- [List Charges (w/ Customer)](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_charges)
- [Refund Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund)

Obviously there are many ways to do this, but this seems to be the easiest in my opinion.

Comment: Using a cron job to periodically reconcile the log of failed operations is an interesting idea. After thinking about this for a while, I have come to the conclusion that there is no 'clever' way to do this, except manually keeping logs...just like actual DBMS do for transactions. Thanks @korben.